# Winforms async delegate - VSTHRD101 or VSTHRD110?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I'm trying to use async delegates in a winforms application, but haven't managed to find a way to avoid a VSTHRD warning, and I was wondering:

a) Is there a way to avoid them entirely? or
b) Which is the 'lesser evil', or
c) If I accept one warning over the other, is there still an issue with exception handling?

My code first looked as follows:

```
this.Load += async (sender, e) =>
{
...
    await AsyncMethod();
...
}
```

Of course, this gives the VSTHRD101 warning:
VSTHRD101 Avoid unsupported async delegates

I followed the pattern given in https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/issues/447 and https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD101.md:

```
var factory = joinableTaskContext.Factory;

this.Load += (sender, e) => factory.RunAsync( async () =>
{
...
    await AsyncMethod(); 
...
}
```

...I now get VSTHRD110, as RunAsync is now discarding the returned Task from RunAsync:

VSTHRD110 Observe result of async calls

I suspect I must be missing something here!  Any input is welcome!

Comment: You should upgrade your visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the [documentation for VSTHRD100](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD100.md#event-handlers), it suggests:

> When using method group syntax as an argument, you can define the method with the required signature, without the async modifier, and define an anonymous delegate or lambda within the method

```
private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _ = joinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(async () =>
   {
      // async code
   });
}
```

Notice the use of `_` to discard the return value (a `JoinableTask` in this case). If you really want to use an anonymous method, you can probably do it like this:

```
var factory = joinableTaskContext.Factory;

this.Load += (sender, e) => { _ = factory.RunAsync( async () =>
    {
    ...
        await AsyncMethod(); 
    ...
    });
};
```